# Power BI UseRelationship Function won't active the inactive relationship

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery

I currently have an active relationship between two tables. 'All Reports' and 'Activity Log' The field in both tables is called [report_id]. I want to create a second inactive relationship between these tables on the [workspace_report_id]. Here is my dax and my model. There are many relationships to my fact table but no ambiguity. Relationship are inactive if they would cause ambiguity.

Last Date Report Modified =
CALCULATE(
'Activity Log'[Views],
'All Reports',
USERELATIONSHIP('All Reports'[workspace_report_id], 'Activity Log'[workspace_report_id])
)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZaIjW.png)

When i run the dax, it's as if the userelationship function never works. The outcome of the measure is as if the original active relationship is on and the inactive relationship never turns on.

Comment: `'Activity Log'[Views]` is a measure, it's better to write as `[Views]`. You doing nothing with a contex change, so `'All Reports'` is a useless expression.

Comment: can you add a code for `[Views]`? How do you apply your measure?

Comment: You want to activate a many to many link, it's not a recommended type of link. It can create uncertainty.

Comment: Views = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Activity Log'[activity_id]),
    FILTER('Activity Type','Activity Type'[Activity] = "viewReport")
)

Report Views = 
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT('Activity Log'[activity_id]),
    FILTER('Activity Type','Activity Type'[Activity] = "viewReport"),
    USERELATIONSHIP('All Reports'[workspace_report_id], 'Activity Log'[workspace_report_id])
)

Comment: For clarity here are two measures. I removed the views measure from them since they didn't matter. They are both calculating the same thing "DistinctCount('Activity Log'[activity_id]. But each are using a different relationship. The crazy thing is, when I remove the original active relationsip, report_id, and turn on the inactive relationship to active in the model, that relationship will work correctly. So it is something with the userelationshp function not working correctly. Not the views measure.

Comment: When you remove original that's 1- many you change it with many-many relation?

Comment: It's hard to give a proper answer without your model. Did you think about getting values and then `TREATAS()`?

Comment: So my original active relationship is 1 - many on report_id. That relationship works perfectly. I included a second inactive relationship which is many - many on workspace_report_id. This relationship will not work with "userelationship", but if i delete the original relationship and turn this many to many relationship active, the measure calculates correctly.

Comment: There is a link to my model in my post

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.